# Azure Mobile Service Filter - Removed?

Tags: c#, azure

I've been reading about custom auth methods using Azure, and stumbled upon [12 Days of ZUMO](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/The_twelve_days_of_ZUMO.aspx). It's an excellent write up, but I can't seem to find anything related to IServiceFilter in the current .Net Client SDK for Azure.

I'm developing a Xamarin app in C#.

Has this functionality been removed or relocated? I have all Azure namespaces referenced and intellisense can't find IServiceFilter or anything else related to service filters.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I currently develop an app for Android on Java (I don't think that library for C# is very different).
And I can access ServiceFilter. But I don't see IServiceFilter.

Namespace - com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.http.ServiceFilter

Library version - 2.0.2-beta2

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin you need to use a `DelegateHandler` instead.  This is the standard .net way to filter http traffic.

```
public class MyLogFilter : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Do any pre-request requirements here
        Log.Warning("http request", request.RequestUri.ToString() );

        // Request happens here
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Do any post-request requirements here
        Log.Warning("http response", response.StatusCode + "  " + response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Once you've done that, you just chain the handler when initializing your `MobileServiceClient`, changing this:

```
Client = new MobileServiceClient (API_URL, new MyExistingHandler());
```

to:

```
Client = new MobileServiceClient (API_URL, new MyLogFilter(), new MyExistingHandler());
```